# Jest clean up after all tests have run

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, reactjs, jasmine, jestjs

Is it possible in Jest to run cleanup or teardown tasks that run after all other tests have completed? Similar to how setupFiles allows one to set up tasks after before any test has run. Bonus points if this can also run regardless if the test had any errors.

Putting `afterAll(() => {})` at the top level of a file (outside any describe function) appears only to run after tests from that particular file have finished.

The use case is I have many test files that will create users in a a development database, and I don't want to make each test file responsible for cleaning up and removing the user afterwards. Errors can also happen while writing tests, so if the cleanup happens regardless of errors that would be preferable.

Comment: I think each test must have fully control over the environment, so each test  must be responsible for its environment. Maybe what you need is to have more than one environment, for example one could be runnung in memory (with a mock implementation of the db) and onother one which really runs with the database.

Comment: could you add a cleanup command in your test runner? ie if you're using gulp, make, grunt etc: `run_your_tests.js; clean_up_database;`

Answer (score 49, accepted):

There's a sibling hook to `setupFiles` that will too fire before every test suite but right after your test runner (by default Jasmine2) has initialised global environment.

It's called [`setupFilesAfterEnv`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#setupfilesafterenv-array). Use it like this:

```
{
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": ["<rootDir>/setup.js"]
}
```

Example *setup.js*:

```js
beforeAll(() => console.log('beforeAll'));
afterAll(() => console.log('afterAll'));
```

`setup.js` doesn't need to export anything. It will be executed before every test suite (every test file). Because test runner is already initialised, global functions like `beforeAll` and `afterAll` are in the scope just like in your regular test file so you can call them as you like.

[image: setupTestFrameworkScriptFile firing beforeAll and afterAll]

Comment: Option "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile" was replaced by configuration "setupFilesAfterEnv", which supports multiple paths.

Comment: I needed globalTeardown (and globalSetup), because I needed to start and stop a parallel service once-per-test-run, not before or after each test suite.

Answer (score 15):

To do some tasks after all test suites finish, use [globalTeardown](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#globalteardown-string). Example:

In package.json:

```
{
  "jest": {
    "globalTeardown": "<rootDir>/teardownJest.js"
  },
}
```

In *teardownJest.js*:

```
const teardown = async () => {
  console.log('called after all test suites');
}

module.exports = teardown;
```

Keep in mind that jest imports every module from scratch for each test suit and teardown file. From [official documentation:](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#resetmodules-boolean)

> By default, each test file gets its own independent module registry

So, you cannot share the same DB module's instance for each test suite or teardown file. Therefore, If you wanted to close db connection after all test suits, this method would not work

Answer (score 14):

In `jest.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
    // ...
    setupFilesAfterEnv: [
        "./test/setup.js",
        // can have more setup files here
    ],
}
```

In `./test/setup.js`:

```js
afterAll(() => { // or: afterAll(async () => { }); to support await calls
    // Cleanup logic
});
```

Note:

- I am using Jest 24.8
- Reference:
  [setupFilesAfterEnv](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#setupfilesafterenv-array)

Answer (score 2):

There looks like there is a feature called a [reporter](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#reporters-arraymodulename--modulename-options) that just does exactly this:

Comment: In this scenario, a setup file would be more relevant IMHO